# bluebird - promise chain return unexpected "true" value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, bluebird, electron

I'm writing an [atom-shell](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell) app using ReactJs. Therefore I wrote `2 simple node.js-modules`. The first fetches an XML api and returns an array of objects. The second is a simple datastore, which should save the fetched dataset. Both modules are *async* utilizing `bluebird`.

Now I have the following scenario:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

store.get()
.tap(print)  //#1: []
.then(function (data) {
    if (data.length) {
        return Promise.resolve(data);  //#6: ? also true in the second run ?
    } else {
        return xmlApi.get()
        .tap(print)  //#2: [...]
        .then(store.insert)  // <-- this returns an array with inserted indices
        .tap(print) //#3: [...]
        -then(store.write)  // <-- this returns all stored objects as array
        .tap(print) //#4: true <-- ? this is, what I doesn't understand... ?
    }
})
.tap(print)  //#5: true
.then(function (data) {
    //Under normal circumstances, I would set ReactJs state from data array...
})
.catch(handleError)
.done();
```

My problem is to understand, why beyond step **#3** everything resolves to `true` instead of `arrays with values`? When testing the libraries in pure node, everything is fine. But also in the second run, when the store holds data, the promise resolves to `true`...

**UPDATE:**

`store.write`

```
var write = Promise.promisify(require('fs').writeFile)

Store.prototype.write = function () {
    return write(this.filename, JSON.stringify(this.data))
    .bind(this)
    .then(function () {
        return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    });
};
```

Comment: Please include the store.write code.  Also are the store methods bound?

Comment: Testing the store with 'simple' ```mocha``` and ```node``` is fine. Problems are since I use this code in ```atom-shell```, which is a customized ```chromium```.

Comment: I still don't think there's enough information in this question to answer it.  You do need to bind to the store instance, `.bind(this).then(store.insert)` or `.then(store.insert.bind(store))`